# can someone help me understand a few things please

Tags: css

hello i have two codes to understand the first question is how does the * get rid of my LI list styling when i not told css to do so this is the code that getting rid of the bullet points

```
 *{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```

and my second question is about div classes i was clawing though facebook's html makeup looking for ideas and i want to know why facebook use a lot of div classes for css when most the code i looked at could easy have been put in one css class i understand css and code being reusable but most of it was just for one div and not use any where else so why would you use multi css statements for one div is this because of readability or optimization or and i missing something and sorry about my english and punctuation

Comment: You should write post titles that reflect the problem, not ask the user for help.

Comment: i dont know what to title it lol because the first question is not a problem my li bullets need to go anyway and i want to know why it happening when my css for li's is not even started being coded yet and the second question is not a problem to me really but want to get the understanding behind it

Answer (score 1):

To get the `margin` and `padding` back to the `<ul><li>` just set it after you used the `*` see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8mbrn3ra/

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }

ul, li {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The other part of your question: I don't know why facebook does the things it does. But one reason could be that you have a `div` as a wrapper of things. If this div has a class with given styles and you want to use them somewhere else you just need to set the class to the wrapper. Understand what I mean?

Comment: yes i understand and my first question i was wondering why my bullet points of my list items are not displaying any more when i not targeted li's with css yet

Comment: @aaronhead if you use `*` in CSS (and many other places it means) it means you set a style to EVERY element. That is what happend. You set no margin and no padding to all (every single one) element. That's why you have to reset later. Normally you will find `* { some: style; } ` always at the beginning of CSS files to reset the default browser behaviours. And then all the following styles you write will be upplied. With `*` you will also set styles to elements you might never need or use. Be careful with that.

Comment: ohhh ok i get it know not much different from what i first thought i thought it ment it would only take the margin and the padding away from elements not all other parts of styles like making the bullet point sit right next to the text without any white space that may explain why i had some problem with my css and html mark up first time i used *

Comment: @aaronhead look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/q222Lkpm/ there you also get a wrapping example with a `<div class="special-wrap">`